# Every story has a 4% chance of being an ad. What's the chance a user will only see 1 ad in 100 stories?

Tags: probability

On a social network, every story in the feed has a 4% chance of being an ad.

What is the chance a user will be shown only a single ad in 100 stories?

What is the chance a user will be shown 10 ads in 100 stories?

What is the chance a user will be shown 0 ads in 100 stories?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the chance a user will be shown $1$ ad in $100$ stories?

$$\binom{100}{1}\times(0.04)^{1}\times(1-0.04)^{100-1}$$

> What is the chance a user will be shown $10$ ads in $100$ stories?

$$\binom{100}{10}\times(0.04)^{10}\times(1-0.04)^{100-10}$$

> What is the chance a user will be shown $0$ ads in $100$ stories?

$$\binom{100}{0}\times(0.04)^{0}\times(1-0.04)^{100-0}$$